# How to do batch row updating using jQuery Datatables and ASP MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4` and the `jQuery Datatables`.

I have a list of servers that I need to populate in the grid.  This is the easy part.  I need editable functionality.  When I select a row I need to be able to edit the data.  I should be able to edit the data of any row.  I don't want updating to take place on cell edit.  When I have done with all the updating then I click on a button.  The button takes all the data in the grid and checks which rows needs to be updated.  Then I do my updating to the data store.

Is this possible with jQuery Datatables and ASP MVC?  The samples that I have seen seems to do the updating after a cell has been edited.

Comment: Please provide at least front end code with JSON backend

Answer (score 2):

I recently worked on a project that had similar use cases. However, I am curious as to why you desire a bulk data update. For my project I paired [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) with [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable). As a guide, you may find ["MVC with jEditable and DataTables plugin for jQuery"](http://weblogs.asp.net/ericpanorel/archive/2012/02/12/MVC-3-and-dataTables.aspx) to be useful. I personally loved the asynchronous data update ability using this combination. Hopefully this points you in the right direction!