# Retrieving all the cell data from a jQuery datatable on post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This question relates to a question that I posted that I'm not getting answered: [How to do batch row updating using jQuery Datatables and ASP MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019172/how-to-do-batch-row-updating-using-jquery-datatables-and-asp-mvc)

I am using the `jQuery datatables` and `ASP.NET MVC 4`.  What I am trying to achieve is when I click on a submit button I need to post back all the datatable's data to my controller's action method.  I will be editing my table data and then I need to post back this edited table data to my controller and then I want to process it all at once.  I don't want row or cell updating on the fly.

I'm not sure how to do this.  I even tried somehing like this but this is also not working:

This is how I populate my datatable:

```
$('#com-plus-components-datatable').dataTable({
     "aoColumns": [
          { "mDataProp": [0], "sWidth": "35%" },
          { "mDataProp": [1], "sWidth": "65%" }
     ],
     "bAutoWidth": false,
     "bFilter": false,
     "bLengthChange": false,
     "bPaginate": false,
     "bProcessing": true,
     "bServerSide": true,
     "bSort": false,
     "iDisplayLength": 50,
     "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("GetWindowsServices")'
});
```

This is my attempt to get the datatable data:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
     $.post("@Url.Content("~/Server/Test")",
     $('form').serialize(),
     function (data) {
          alert('success');
     }, 'json');
});
```

My action method to get my data and to do all processing (partial code below):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string[] data)
{
     return View();
}
```

`string[] data` is always null on post.

How do I get all my datatable's data into my action method after I clicked the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to cancel the default action of the form submit by returning false from your .submit handler:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
     $.post('@Url.Action("Test", "Server")', $('form').serialize(), function (data) {
         alert('success');
     });
     return false; // <!-- You need this
});
```

or you could also do this:

```
$('form').submit(function (evt) {
     evt.preventDefault(); // <!-- You need this
     $.post('@Url.Action("Test", "Server")', $('form').serialize(), function (data) {
         alert('success');
     });
});
```

Also notice how I have used the Url.Action helper instead of Url.Content to generate the url to your controller action. This will take into account your route definitions. It's always bad to hardcode your urls.

Also for this to work make sure that you have respected the [`standard naming conventions`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) of your input fields so that the default model binder will be able to deserialize the request into a string array.

Comment: Thanks. Look at my HttpPost action method above, the front end is displaying my success popup but it is not hitting my action method. Why would this be?

Comment: I'm trying to post back all the values in my grid that was loaded via an AJAX/JSON call. That is why I used `string[] data`.

Comment: I got the name to work for input textboxes. But when working with table data I can't get add a name for a TABLE and TD using HTML5. What do I do now? It doesn't pick it up.

Comment: Why do you want to add a name attribute to your TABLE and TD elements? This doesn't make any sense. The name attribute should be added to the input fields whose values you are trying to send to the server. If on the other hand you do not have any input fields in your table and want to send some static data then this is an entirely different story.

Comment: I have an HTML table, I want to get the values in the table. How do I do this? The table that I have displays but when I use the code above it's not hitting my action method with the data in it. The name part comes from Phil's article.

Comment: Why are you using `$('form').serialize()` then if you do not even have input fields? In order to do this you will have to harvest the values you want to send to your server from this table and prepare the request manually.

Comment: Well I'm not hitting my action method with the table data which I need. It is not inputed elements, it's just plain text in the cells of the table. Have you got sample code of what you mentioned above?